# Curve Fitting Rheology Data to Carreau-Yasuda Model

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit some rheology data to a model. Using an array of viscosities and shear rates, I would like to fit it to the Carreau model, but the curve_fit function in scipy is not giving me particuarly good values (I have plotted what I received after and it only follows the data for about half of it). Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, Data, RealData
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")


df = pd.read_excel('Biomass.xls', sheet_name=1,)

data_array = df.to_numpy()
data_array_numbers = np.delete(data_array, 0, 0)
data_array_numbers = np.delete(data_array_numbers, 0, 0)
transposed_array = data_array_numbers.transpose()
sorted_array = transposed_array[:, np.argsort( transposed_array[1])]
shear_rate = np.array(sorted_array[1])
viscosity = np.array(sorted_array[2])


density=1000
for i in range(0, len(viscosity)):
    viscosity[i] = viscosity[i]/density
    
    
    
log_shear = np.zeros(shape=(len(shear_rate)))
log_viscosity = np.zeros(shape=(len(shear_rate)))
log_shear[i] = np.log(shear_rate[i])
log_viscosity[i] = np.log(viscosity[i])


def log_powerlaw(x, log_k, n_p):
    nu = log_k + n_p*x
    return nu

def powerlaw(x, k, n):
    return k*(x)**(n-1)

def carreau(x, n_inf, n_0, lamda, a, n):
    return n_inf + (n_0-n_inf)*(1+(x*lamda)**a)**((n-1)/a)


params, covariance = curve_fit(carreau, xdata=shear_rate, ydata=viscosity, maxfev=200000, method='trf')

n_inf_fit, n_0_fit, lambda_fit, a_fit, n_fit = params
print(n_inf_fit)
print(n_0_fit)
print(lambda_fit)
print(a_fit)
print(n_fit)
ax = plt.axes()
plt.scatter(shear_rate, viscosity, c='g', marker='x')
plt.plot(shear_rate, carreau(shear_rate, n_inf_fit, n_0_fit, lambda_fit, a_fit, n_fit ), c='b')
#plt.plot(shear_rate, powerlaw(shear_rate, k=params[0], n=params[1]) )
ax.set_title("Biomass Rheology")
ax.set_ylabel('Viscosity')
ax.set_xlabel('Shear Rate')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Have tried to think of a way to linearise the problem, as I did for a power-law fit (taking logs to make it a straight line equation), tried giving different initial guesses. I would expect a good approximation since the model has 5 parameters.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [mcve] and [ask]. Could you compete your post with dataset sample in order to reproduce and specify what would be the expected output in term of parameters.

Comment: Having 5 parameters does not always mean better fitness, in this peculiar example it also means more complex error landscape with extra minima making the fitting procedure harder to converge to the optimum. Do you have any crude estimate of mu_0 and mu_inf?

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

It's possible to fit parameters for such a model but it needs a bit help such as initial guess or constraints (crude estimate on viscosity constants at least).

#### MCVE

Let's generate some data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def model(x, n_0, n_inf, lamda, a, n):
    return n_inf + (n_0 - n_inf) * np.power((1 + np.power((x[:, 0] * lamda), a)), ((n - 1) / a))

np.random.seed(12345)
parameters = (4e-2, 5e-4, 1.6, 2.1, 0.3)
X = np.logspace(-4, 4, 30, base=10).reshape(-1, 1)
y = model(X, *parameters)
sigma = 1e-6 * np.ones(y.size)
y += sigma * np.random.normal(size=y.size)
```

Then we have two options: using the LM algorithm with a bit of help for coupled constants (at least magnitude).

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(
    model, X, y, sigma=sigma, absolute_sigma=True,
    p0=(1e-2, 1e-4, 1, 1, 1)
)
# array([3.99998407e-02, 4.99859627e-04, 1.59989329e+00, 2.10012984e+00, 2.99977836e-01]
```

Or adding constraints on the problem.

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(
    model, X, y, sigma=sigma, absolute_sigma=True,
    method="trf", bounds=[(1e-3, 1e-5, 0, 0, 0), (1e-1, 1e-3, 10, 3, 1)]
)
# array([3.99998407e-02, 4.99859627e-04, 1.59989329e+00, 2.10012983e+00, 2.99977836e-01]
```

Both methods returns the initial parameters with fairly good consistency.

[image]
[image]